# Revising a bash script - Invoking a change of prompt color via a temporary file

Tags: script, bash-scripting

I am wondering why the following script won't work:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p 'First lets write PROMPT.SH'
echo '#!/bin/bash'>prompt.sh
echo "export PS1='\e[1;31m\]\u@\h \W\$\e[0m\] '">>prompt.sh
read -p "Change Title and Prompt"
source prompt.sh
echo texttexttext
read -p "Now lets tidy up PROMPT.SH"
rm ./prompt.sh
read -p "That was the program"
```

What I am trying to do is change the window title, prompt, and text color that I can normally do with,

```
PS1='\e[1;31m\]\u@\h \W\$\e[0m\] '
```

during a regular bash session but not when I add it to a script and then run the script.

Answer (score 0):

`PS1` is only displayed for interactive prompts. It has nothing to do with the prompt shown for `read -p`. Execution of a bash script, even if reading input, is not considered *interactive*.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not crystal clear on what you’re trying to do, but I guess it’s setting `PS1` for your interactive shell from a script.  Stated like that, you cannot do it.  In *nix and Unix-like systems, process characteristics/ properties get passed from parent to child, but never the other way around.  For example, if you set your `PATH` to include `/foo`, and then you run a script that tries to run `bar`, it will find `/foo/bar` — but if you change `PATH` in a script, it doesn’t affect your interactive shell.  Likewise for `cd` and `umask`. These are differences from the Windows Command Prompt (batch) world.

That said, there is an answer, and you already know it.  If your script (the 10-line one) is called `andy.sh`, then you should be able to get the effect you want by typing `source andy.sh`.  But that’s silly overkill (unless you’re doing it just for script-writing practice); just put

```
PS1='\e[1;31m\]\u@\h \W\$\e[0m\] '
```

into `drew.sh` and type `source drew.sh`.

But also research the `alias` command.